# Dropping creation/annihilation terms when quantising a field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory

There is something I don't understand in the procedure that is often done while quantising a field theory.

Say, we have operators $a_k, a^{\dagger}_k, b_k, b^{\dagger}_k$ which obey the commutation relations (not anti-). 
When determining the conserved charge we run into the following group of terms:
\begin{align*}
a^{\dagger}_k b^{\dagger}_{-k} + b^{\dagger}_{k} a^{\dagger}_{-k} - a_{k} b_{-k} - b_{k} a_{-k} 
\end{align*}
times some terms proportional to $k$ or $k^0$ (I'm trying to be general, but have only seen a few examples), integrated over $\mathrm{d}^3k$. Notice that I treat $k$ as a 3-wavevector and $k^0$ as the fourth, or zeroth component.
Actually, for completeness, I'll put the actual integral here in case there is no 'principle' to dealing with these, but situational tricks:
\begin{align*}
\int \mathrm{d}^3 x : j^{0} := \frac{i \alpha}{2} \int \mathrm{d}^3 k \bigg( \partial^{0} \frac{1}{k^{0}} \bigg) \frac{1}{k^0} \bigg\{ a^{\dagger}_k b^{\dagger}_{-k} + b^{\dagger}_{k} a^{\dagger}_{-k} - a_{k} b_{-k} - b_{k} a_{-k} + 2 a^{\dagger}_k a_k - 2 b^{\dagger}_k b_k \bigg\}
\end{align*}
or that's what I got anyway after normal ordering.

I'm trying to see why these vanish. Attempts to explanation:

First I was also confused by something similar: $a^{\dagger}_{-k} a^{\dagger}_{-k}$, but made the rationalization that that has to be even, so when multiplied by something like $k$ it becomes odd and disappears when integrating over the whole $k$-space. But similar arguments can't be made here, I think.
The normal ordering procedure does not (?) touch these, as it simply rearranges the dagger-terms to the left. Unless that would bring about some ambiguity as to which of $a^{\dagger}_k b^{\dagger}_{-k}$ and $b^{\dagger}_{k} a^{\dagger}_{-k}$ is the normal-ordered one. I'm not convinced though.
Next, some physics. Since $a$ and $b$ refer to different particles, the above operator pairs should commute. That shouldn't be the whole story though because in these pairs we always create/annihilate particles of opposite wave vector.
Maybe the energy is not conserved, then? Opposite wave vectors still have the same length i.e. correspond to a particle with same energy. Right? (My only problem is that this particular example comes from an example whose EOM resembles the Klein-Gordon equation except that the field is complex, and solutions to that have either positive or negative energy.) And if the conserved charge has to conserve in processes where energy is conserved, that would rule the terms out.

I feel like I'm just forgetting something really basic here.

EDIT:
There is another possibility as well. $k^0$ or its derivative is not integrated over, so it doesn't contribute to the products being odd/even. Then, if I do assume that the order of creation/annihilation of $a$ and $b$-particles can be freely exchanged, I would get that the functions $f(k) \equiv a_k b_{-k} - a_{-k} b_{k}$ and $g(k) \equiv a^{\dagger}_k b^{\dagger}_{-k} - a^{\dagger}_{-k} b^{\dagger}_{k}$ are clearly odd, and thus vanish during the integration.